# Win 8.1 won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have read alot about dual booting ubuntu and windows, but I have not seen an answer to my situation.  I have an HP G17 laptop.  I removed the HD and put in a 240 GB SSD and installed Win 8.1.  Works beautifully.  I removed the CD/DVD and installed a HD Caddy with a 120GB SSD.  It has Ubuntu 10.04LTS, Ubuntu 14.04LTS and Mint 16 in 3 partitions.
I can get to all for operating systems with both drives in place.
Grub 2 menu on the 240 will load mint 16, 14.04 and win 8.1.
Grub 1.98 menu on the 120 will load 10.04, mint 16, 14.04 and 8.1.
My problem comes in when I remove the 120 and put in the CD/DVD drive, all I get is grub rescue and can not access win 8.1 or CD/DVD.
I want 8.1 with no grub menu so when I change boot order to 240 it will boot into 8.1.
Then when I change boot order to 120 the grub menu gives me the 3 ubuntu options.
When I boot 8.1 the error I get is: no such device: a5f413dd-a6d0-4d0b-8809-657120d674cd.
When I run bcdedit, it gives a different ID which must be for win 8.1.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,

Gencom

Comment: Post link to BootInfo report so we can see details.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I also can't use grub to boot into windows on my Acer. The only solution is to hit F2 during boot and select windows to boot in the BIOS. You may have to do this too.

Comment: When I use bios to boot to 240 HD I get grub error.  Something in 8.1 is loading grub with wrong ID for 8.1. Using 14.04 files to search 8.1 files, there are many files that I can not access from 8.1.  I need to know what file has grub.cfg that should load 8.1 with only 8.1 disk installed.

Comment: Update. Using bootrec /fixmbr with only 240 installed fixed the problem. Adding 120 and I get Grub 2 menu minus 10.04 which is fixable.